# python code broken every character is triangle

Tags: python, python-unicode

I have a python script that I wrote a while ago (2 years).

Now I need to open that .py file to see what I did. I opened the file in Spyder 3. and all I see is like the attached image.

What happened and how should I fix this problem? all characters are triangles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you open it with anything else does this still happen? like notepad++

Comment: That doesn't look encouraging. Where was the file stored in the interim? Do you have another copy?

Comment: You're probably opening it with the wrong encoding. Either that or the file is corrupted.

Comment: Try opening it with your most basic editor (Wordpad, Nano ...). If that yields the same results and you are opening the file with the right encoding, it would seem that the file is corrupted.

Comment: Use `hd myscript.py` to display the binary content of the file and post that instead of a screenshot of a gui application. If you are on windows, use powershell's `Format-Hex` instead of `hd`.

Comment: @AlexisDrakopoulos I tried opening it with Spyder3, Spyder2 and gedit. All same result as the image shows.

Comment: @Chris It was store in one of my project folders all the time for little over 2 years.

Comment: @JonathanRys If the file is corrupted, then is there any way for me to fix it?

Comment: Not unless you have a backup.

Comment: @BramVanroy I opened it with nano, same result

Comment: @HåkenLid I just did hd and attached the outcome. Now what I can do next ?

Comment: There's not much you can do other than set up an account on GitHub and use version control in the future.  That way you'll have your code backed up.

Comment: The file content must have been overwritten. There's no trace of the previous python script, just a sequence of zero bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your python code has passed on. This script is no more. It has ceased to be. It's expired and gone to meet its garbage collector. It's a stiff. Bereft of life. It rests in peace. Since you didn't use git, it's pushing up the daisies. Its binary processes are now history. It's off the heap. It's kicked the bitbucket. It's shuffled off its virtual coil, run down the process chain and joined the bleedin' /dev/null choir! This is an ex-python!*

---

In short, there's no meaningful information left in this file that can be used to restore the script you once wrote. So you will have to write a new script from scratch. And this time, you should use `git` to maintain a version control history, even if it's just a tiny script for your own use.